# How can I remove the skin from peanuts?

Tags: sauce

I will be making Ban ban ji chicken for tonight's dinner, and have picked up some shelled peanuts. The peanuts are still in their skins, and I was wondering: what is the best way to remove the skins from peanuts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a clean kitchen towel (not a terry towel, a dish towel), place the peanuts on it, fold it up, then rub the peanuts vigorously through the towel. The friction should remove the skins. You can then pass the whole lot through a colander to winnow out the skins.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

Stir the peanuts in a pan (preferably a non stick pan) on a low flame for 5 minutes making sure they don't stick to the pan. Then take it off the stove and allow it to cool. Rub them with your hands to remove the already loosened skin.